# Dependencies conflict error while adding admob gradle to android app

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies, admob

I want to add google admob to one of my android app.
But it shows dependency conflict error while adding google services ads and firebase ads.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.espresso:espressocore:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
        implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
        implementation 'com.sasank.roundedhorizontalprogress:roundedhorizontalprogress:1.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.tomer:fadingtextview:2.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any help will be highly appericated

Answer (score 0):

Check your project gradle if this is added -

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add admob when you have `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0`, it include admob.

You are trying to ad admob twice, hence the error.

---

You can also remove

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0'
```

Because it's also part of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both firebase-ads and play-services-ads. You should use only one of them. If you're using firebase-ads follow [Firebase ads guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) or follow [Google Admob guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) if you're planning to use Standard alone Google Admob SDK

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
```

You can check the [official release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

> **Warning:** This release is a **MAJOR** version update and breaking change.
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:

Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app **to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.

Also the 'firebase-ads' dependency just brings in the existing 'play-services-ads' library. The Firebase SDK is part of Google Play services.

Comment: so i removed firebase ads dependency and downgrade google service ads version to 17.2.1 but my app didnt show ads it shows error code 2 for banner ad and error code 3 for Interstitial ad. can you tell me whats the problem in that !!

Comment: It is a different issue. You can try to post the error or open another question. In any case before or after you have to migrate to androidx.